# how to use promises and try catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have the following code

```
var promise = getRaids(client);
promise.then(function (raids) {
    res.json(raids);
}, function (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.send(403, { error: err});
});
```

I want to transform that to a try catch block, I think it is much more readable.
What would the code look like?

Comment: Try/Catch does not work with promises, that's what you got the error function for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to transform this to a try/catch block.  Doing that would require blocking on the promise inside the try block, and JavaScript doesn't allow blocking on promises.

Answer (score 1):

Use promises like this and it will be as readable:

```
getRaids(client)
.then(function (raids) {
    res.json(raids);
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.send(403, { error: err});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to, you can use Harmony with node.js and [use generators](http://tobyho.com/2013/06/16/what-are-generators/):

> When you throw() an error onto a generator object, the error actually
>   propagates back up into the code of the generator, meaning you can
>   actually use the try and catch statements to catch it.

If you're going for readability with promises, [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when/) provides an [extended promise API](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#extended-promise-api) that allows for keywords such as `catch` and `finally`. I'm sure  Q and other promise libraries have similar mechanisms.

```js
promise.then(function() {

}).catch(function(error) {

}).finally(function() {
    // cleanup / etc.
});
```

Comment: Q.js does indeed offer `.catch()` and `.finally()` but please remember that neither method offers the filtering power of `.then()`, ie the ability to return a new resolved or unresolved Promise. You may therefore need `promise.then(...).catch(...).finally(...);` (as above), `promise.catch(...).finally(...).then(...);` or even `promise.then(...).catch(...).finally(...).then(...);`, depending on circumstances.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `Q` promises. However, with `when.js` promises you can return a new promise in a `catch()`, e.g. `promise.then(...).catch(function(err) { return newPromise; })`. You can't return a new promise from a `finally(...)`, but I don't see a use case for why anyone would ever want to.